# List of objects to nested objects using aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping

I'm having the following documents in a collection

```
[
  {
    "category":"category1",
    "type":"type1",
    "item":"item1",
    "name":"testname",
    "settings":{
      "enable":"true",
      "mode":"1"
    },
    "status":"active"
  },
  {
    "category":"category1",
    "type":"type1",
    "item":"item1",
    "name":"testname2",
    "settings":{
      "enable":"true",
      "mode":"1"
    },
    "status":"inactive"
  },
  {
    "category":"category1",
    "type":"type1",
    "item":"item2",
    "name":"testname3",
    "settings":{
      "enable":"true",
      "mode":"1"
    },
    "status":"active"
  },
  {
    "category":"category2",
    "type":"type2",
    "item":"item3",
    "name":"testname4",
    "settings":{
      "enable":"true",
      "mode":"1"
    },
    "status":"active"
  },
  {
    "category":"category3",
    "type":"type4",
    "item":"item5",
    "name":"testname5",
    "settings":{
      "enable":"true",
      "mode":"1"
    },
    "status":"active"
  }
]
```

I want to convert this into nested objects with four level. Expecting output like below

```
{
  "category1":{
    "type1":{
      "item1":{
        "active":[
          {
            "name":"testname",
            "settings":{
              "enable":"true",
              "mode":"1"
            }
          }
        ],
        "inactive":[
          {
            "name":"testname2",
            "settings":{
              "enable":"true",
              "mode":"1"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "item2":{
        "active":[
          {
            "name":"testname3",
            "settings":{
              "enable":"true",
              "mode":"1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "category2":{
    "type2":{
      "item3":{
        "active":[
          {
            "name":"testname4",
            "settings":{
              "enable":"true",
              "mode":"1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "category3":{
    "type4":{
      "item4":{
        "active":[
          {
            "name":"testname5",
            "settings":{
              "enable":"true",
              "mode":"1"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm able to convert into two levels with aggregate and replaceRoot option. Unable to convert into four levels after replacing the root. How to achieve this output using mongo aggregate>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how your pipeline looks as you didn't include it, however here is how I would do it by using [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/), [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) to manipulate the structure into the required format:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        category: "$category",
        type: "$type",
        item: "$item",
        status: "$status"
      },
      data: {
        $push: {
          name: "$name",
          settings: "$settings"
        },
        
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        category: "$_id.category",
        type: "$_id.type",
        item: "$_id.item"
      },
      statusData: {
        $push: {
          data: "$data",
          status: "$_id.status"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            _id: "$_id"
          },
          {
            data: {
              "$arrayToObject": {
                $map: {
                  input: "$statusData",
                  as: "datum",
                  in: {
                    k: "$$datum.status",
                    v: "$$datum.data"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.item": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        category: "$_id.category",
        type: "$_id.type"
      },
      items: {
        $push: {
          "$arrayToObject": [
            [
              {
                k: "$_id.item",
                v: "$data"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "_id.type": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              k: "$_id.category",
              v: {
                "$arrayToObject": [
                  [
                    {
                      k: "$_id.type",
                      v: {
                        "$mergeObjects": "$items"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/B15mapsLWhf)

Comment: Thanks for the answe. However, The above aggregate doesn't return in the expected format. The second level (type) should be of json object but this gives in list

Comment: Is it just the sorting order that's an issue? add `$sort` stage. is there a different issue i'm missing?

Comment: It's not with sorting
Expected in level 2
 "type2":{
          "item3":[
            {
              "name":"testname4",
              "settings":{
                "enable":"true",
                "mode":"1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
Actual Result
"type2": [
        {
          "item3": [
            {
              "name": "testname4",
              "settings": {
                "enable": "true",
                "mode": "1"
              }
            }
          ]
        }

Comment: the type level should be object not array

Comment: Ok i'll fix it real quick, is the sort on the `type` or on the `category`?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your comments, i added sort on the `type` but feel free to change it to be on the `category` if needed. i also fixed the items array structure.

Comment: Thanks @tom. That was really quick and works well. It would be great if you could help me in adding one more level grouping. I have edited my question and expected output

Comment: This was a little more tricky to do, we have to add another `$group` stage initially on status, then replace the root with the new constructed object:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/B15mapsLWhf